Link-local IPv6 address unpingable through guest VM
We have multiple virtualizor based KVM VM provisioning hosts and none of the VMs can ping link-local IPv6 Addresses. To simplify:
VM <--> VM Host: working
VM <--> VM: not working
VM <--> Router: not working
VM Host <--> Router: working
VM Host <--> (Any other devices on the same L3): working
Virtualizor support simply said "They're dummy, cannot be pinged and are local server only" so I've no hope that they even know how all this works and whether they can help me troubleshoot. The VM, VM Host and Router are on the same L3 and they can ping IPv6 global addresses perfectly. Only VM's IPv6 link-local connectivity has a problem which leads me to believe the likely problem might be either on VM or VM Host but I've no idea where to start looking.
Any suggestions?
